# Android Studio/Java null object reference - can't seem to edit fragment variable from activity

Tags: java, android, object, reference, null

Ok, I'm new to Android Studio so bear with me here if this is a silly question but I've been researching for hours trying to figure out why I can't do this and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a MainActivity and 2 fragments.  I'm trying to edit public variables (Lists) within the fragments from the main activity.  Here's how I've gone about doing it so far.

Inside MainActivity I have the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Form.sendFormData, Chart.chartData {

    private Form form = new Form();
    private Chart chart = new Chart();

    public MainActivity() {
        this.form = (Form) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentForm);
        this.chart = (Chart) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentChart);
    }

...
```

Form and Chart are my 2 fragments, neither of which will let me edit their publicly declared variables.

Here's what it looks like at the start of my Chart class:

```
public class Chart extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Chart";

    PieChart chart;

    public List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

What I'm trying to do is access `entryList` via MainActivity by doing the following: `chart.entryList.add(...);`.  However when I execute the method and it gets to that line of code (or any line of code that attempts to read/change a variable inside a fragment from MainActivity I get the null object reference.

I have interfaces set up in each of the fragments for sending information from the Fragment to the MainActivity.  Am I supposed to use the same interface to send information from MainActivity to the Fragments and if so how?

Here's the logcat:

```
05-03 00:44:10.873 29594-29594/com.mptests.rafflemore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mptests.rafflemore, PID: 29594
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.List com.mptests.rafflemore.Chart.entryList' on a null object reference
at com.mptests.rafflemore.MainActivity.onSubmitEntry(MainActivity.java:61)
at com.mptests.rafflemore.Form.submitEntry(Form.java:139)
at com.mptests.rafflemore.Form$1.onClick(Form.java:74)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

EDIT:

I should mention that the code executes if I declare `form` and `chart` as follows and don't try to reference them to their fragment id's:

```
private Form form = new Form();
private Chart chart = new Chart();
```

However when I do it that way the fragments don't actually update with the data I want to change within them.  So I assume that the problem lies within the reference to the fragments at `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.---);`.  I just can't seem to understand why the reference is null.

Comment: post appropriate code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use static keyword as following in your fragment:

```
public static List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hey it works!  Thanks so much!  Any chance you can explain why that needs to happen?  I don't understand why the methods and variables need to be static to be changed from within Main Activity.

Comment: If you want access variable of one java class in another java class, you have to declare it using static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt is correct.
The problem is here:

```
public MainActivity() {
    this.form = (Form) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentForm);
    this.chart = (Chart) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentChart);
}
```

You can not assign form and chart here.
Here, there is no view been infalted. So the 
findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentForm) and findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentChart) will be null.

You can assgin them in onCreate()

```
@Override
onCreate() {
    setContentVew(R.layout.my_view);

    this.form = (Form) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentForm);
    this.chart = (Chart) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentChart);
}
```

I don't like that once you meet a problem, only use static.
You can try to find why it happens.